# Is data coming from cache?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession, nscache, nsurlsessionconfiguration, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

Requirement: Get the data from the cache if `NSMutableURLRequest` can not fetch data from the server.If internet available and i got the data from the server then function will return server data but if request fail to get the data from the server then function will return the `NSCache` data according to `cachePolicy`.

To resolve this issue i changed the `cachePolicy` from `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` to `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`. Now I am getting the data from `NSCache`.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest=TimeOfRequestOut;
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad //HERE IS THE CHANGE
                                                   timeoutInterval:TimeOfRequestOut];
```

Now, I need to find out when this function returning `NSCache` data and when it's returning data from live server and It will also helpful, if someone tell me is it right approach to get cache data?

Comment: Yes! you can do it more complex worked by NSDiscardableContent protoco.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is home task question,